# Is there some reference as to what these numbers exactly signify in ConEmu color setting

Tags: terminal, conemu

I realize that `0.` is the background and figured out some of the others by playing around with the colors. But looking online for some interesting color schemes, I see other color settings using a [Base16](http://chriskempson.github.io/base16/#flat) set up that have other identifiers like `00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F` Is there a reference guide for matching the two different identifiers?

[image: My current settings]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ConEmu colors exactly match to [Windows real console](http://conemu.github.io/en/RealConsole.html) color indexes.

[image: Windows RealConsole palette]

As you can see, they match (by order) lower box of any ConEmu palette (if `Extend foreground colors` is not used).

[image: ConEmu palette]

But ANSI X3.64 color indexes are [different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors). That's why in the upper box of ConEmu palette some cells has two 0-based indexes. `1/4` means 1-st color from Windows palette and 4-th color from ANSI palette.

At last, ANSI palette defines only 8 colors instead of 16 as in Windows. However ANSI defines two codes for background/foreground intensity to be able address indexes 8-15 from Windows palette.

PS. As for `0F` read about [hex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal).

Comment: Why don't people mention stuff like this in their documentation?  Not everyone is neck-deep in console references, so I think at least 90% of the people reading the docs don't have a clue about this.